# get element of datatype with id in haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have two datatypes look like this:

```
data DataType1 = DataType1 { id :: Int, values :: [Int]} deriving (Show)
data DataType2 = DataType2 { dataType1Id :: Int, values2 :: [Int]} deriving (Show)
```

Now I want to compare the average of values and the related values2 (so where DataType1Id = id).
I am pretty new in Haskell so I don't know if this is possible.

This is my function to compare the averages:

```
isGreaterAvgThen :: DataType2 -> Bool
isGreaterAvgThen x
    | average (values2 x) > average (values y) = True
    | otherwise = False
    where y = ...
```

average is a function that calculates the average of a list of Ints (average :: [Int] -> Double)

Comment: What happens when you compile it?

Comment: nothing at the moment, i don't know what y = ... should be here. I have list of DataType1s and I am trying to do something like DataType1 where id of DataType1 = (dataType1Id x).

Comment: How many `DataType2`s do you have?  It sounds like you are saying you have a single one, and you need to single out the `DataType1` from a list....  Also, would `DataType1` be better stored as a `Data.Map Int [Int]`?

Comment: I have a list of DataType2 which I want to filter with isGreaterAvgThen. So I have two list one with DataType1 and one with DataType2

Comment: It's pretty unusual to define anything called `id` yourself. That almost always means the identity function from `Prelude`. The rest of the time (rarely), it almost always means an identity morphism from an instance of `Control.Category.Category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
where y = fromMaybe (error "missing value") $ 
                     find ((== id x) . dataType1Id) listOfDataType2
```

Since the list might be missing the desired value, the type of `find` is wrapped in Maybe....  If you are sure that it is there, you can unwrap it with `fromMaybe` like I did, but be warned, `error` is just another way to say "crash"....